# How to consume ASP.NET (Razor) User Control OR MVC User Control in Layout Page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC 3: Add usercontrol to Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317317/mvc-3-add-usercontrol-to-razor-view)

It's simple to create both user control from the two world : ASP.NET+Razor or MVC 3.0.

But i do not known how to consume the user control FROM the razor "_layout.chtml" page.

I want to put such thing within the layout page:

```
<uc:MyTag Prop1="" Prop2="" />
```

So i need to declare this directive at top of the layout file :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyTag" Src="Controls/Mytag.ascx" %>
```

BUT it does not work, help please !!!!
It seems that <% is not allowed in razor "_layout.chtml" page.

Thank you

Comment: Your title is confusing.  Are you attempting to consume a Web Forms user control in a MVC3 application using Razor?

Comment: This question has been asked/answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317317/mvc-3-add-usercontrol-to-razor-view)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a shared view like this

```
Html.RenderPartial("Mytag", model);
```

Comment: Thank you but Html.RenderPartial does not exist in ASP.NET+Razor and it does not work under MVC 3 because MVC does not find the right extension method to call.

Comment: It works for me in razor @Html.Partial("RoundCornersBottom")

Comment: Maybe, i badly created my user control, the file named "MyTag.ascx" is created under Views/Shared/MyTag.ascx. it contains 2 lines: (1) <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %> (2) Hello from my user control

Comment: Hmm i dont know if it works for ascx file but it works for schtml

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is correct, that you are attempting to consume a Web Forms usercontrol in MVC using the Razor view engine (two seperate entities), then I would take a look at doing [something like this](http://malvinly.com/2011/02/28/using-web-forms-user-controls-in-an-asp-net-mvc-project/).